# Problem creating a child record to a database view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, view

I have created a database view (basketball_players) which is the parent to a regular table (watchlist_players):

```
class BasketballPlayer < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :id
  has_many :watchlist_players, foreign_key: 'player_id' 
end

class WatchlistPlayer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :watchlist
  belongs_to :basketball_player

  enum status: [:prospect, :pending, :ignore]
end
```

When I try to create a child record, I get the error that the parent doesn't exist. For example, from the console:

> bb_player = BasketballPlayer.first
> => #<BasketballPlayer:.... id: 202, name: "Heather N Yonn" ...

> watchlist = Watchlist.first
> => #<Watchlist:... id: 260, domain: 1, ...

> watchlist_player = WatchlistPlayer.new(watchlist_id: watchlist.id, player_id: bb_player.id)
> => #<WatchlistPlayer:... id: nil, watchlist_id: 260, player_id: 202, ...)

> watchlist_player.save
> => false

> watchlist_player.errors.full_messages
> => ["Basketball player must exist"]

Does anyone understand what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: There's something confusing about the question - the terminal print-out of your WatchlistPlayer model implies the existence of a "player_id" and a `belongs_to :player` or `belongs_to :basketball_player, foreign_key: :player_id` association, however your model only defines `belongs_to :basketball_player`. Based on your question I expect that setting `player_id` is supposed to setup the `basketball_player`. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the error "Basketball player must exist" because the belongs-to association is required by default ([since rails 5](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default)) and because the Basketball Player object is not found.

So, a "fix" to the problem would be to make the basketball player association optional, or to ensure that a basketball player exists. You can make the association optional with:

```
belongs_to :basketball_player, optional: true
```

To set the basketball player on the watchlist_player, you need to assign an ID to the foreign key used by the `belongs_to` association. By default, a association named `basketball_player` will look at the `basketball_player_id` field. You're setting a `player_id` field. If you want `player_id` to populate the `basketball_player` association, define the association to use that foreign key like this:

```
belongs_to :basketball_player, foreign_key: :player_id
```

Or set `basketball_player_id` to a valid id for the rows in that view.

It could also be helpful to understand what you're trying to accomplish here. In my experience it's a best practice to setup associations as [database foreign keys](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/referential-integrity-with-foreign-keys) whenever possible so that you can use database referential integrity. You can't setup a database foreign key to a view, only to the underlying table, so I'd generally recommend setting up your associations with referential integrity to the underlying tables rather than to the view itself.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the foreign_key option to the "belongs_to" worked. As you can see in my question, I had defined the foreign_key in the "has_many" for the parent view. Do I need the foreign key defined for both the parent and child or did I just get it backwards?

Comment: Regarding database referential integrity to the underlying tables - since the link to the tables is through the view, how can this be set up without a database foreign key to the view? The whole idea of the view is to flatten a very large, highly relational database to speed up updates to the watchlist_player table.